# OpenLDAP CentOS apply LDIF takes ages

Tags: centos, openldap, slapd

When I apply LDIF scripts through ldap_modify it takes ages on a running multi-master setup before they are applied. I don't see any lead in the logfiles what could cause this issue.

I think it has to do with DNS name resolution because I know some of the nodes can't reach one-another (on purpose).

Any ideas if I am on the right track?

I have all nodes hardcoded in /etc/hosts so it should resolve fast but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in the past and I tried this:

1. get into with sudo /etc/ldap.conf

And look for this line:

```
ssl start tls
```

add AFTER that line:

```
ssl on
```

2. Get into smb.conf with sudo

and remove:

```
ldap ssl = start tls
```

but leave the line

```
passdb backend = ldapsam:ldaps://yourserver:1234
```

Note that the line above will differ from this one.

Hope you solve it.

Regards.

C.